# Expected number of socks needed to draw

Tags: probability, expected-value

Suppose you have 3 drawers. One drawer has infinitely many red and green socks. Another drawer has infinitely many green and blue socks. The last drawer has infinitely many red and blue socks.

What's the expected number of draws you need to make in order to conclude which drawer is which?

---

I tried a lot of case work and got $4.5$, but I'm not sure if that is right. I am sort of just guessing, so I would appreciate some help on this problem

Comment: Just off the top of my head, I get $5$, so I'd really like to see how you got $4.375.$

Comment: I get $\frac 14\times 4+\frac 34\times 5=4.75$

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that in drawing from a drawer, the probability of getting either of the colors in the drawer is $0.5$?

Answer (score 3):

A preliminary point: After you have seen one color of drawer $D_i$ then the expected number $E$ of additional draws to learn the other color of $D_i$ satisfies
$$E=1+{1\over2}\, E\ ,$$
because the first such draw gives you with probability ${1\over2}$ the color that you already know. It follows that $E=2$, and that we should try to avoid  this procedure.

Therefore we take one sock from drawer $D_1$ and one sock from  $D_2$. These two socks have the same color with probability ${1\over4}$, and have different colors with probability ${3\over4}$. In the first case we know the colors of  $D_3$, and have to expect $2$ more drawings to find the the second color of  $D_1$, which then also reveils the second color of  $D_2$. In the second case we draw one sock from $D_3$ and then have either three different socks or two equal socks, one from $D_3$,  and another sock. We have to expect $2$ more drawings to find the other color of $D_3$, and then everything will be determined.

This shows that the expected number $E_{\rm total}$ of necessary drawings is given by
$$E_{\rm total}={1\over4}(2+2)+{3\over4}(2+1+2)=4.75\ .$$

Comment: IMHO this is not quite a full answer because it doesn't prove that your strategy is optimal.  One alternate strategy is to draw repeatedly from $D_1$ first.  This requires on average $5$ draws so is suboptimal.  The more tedious case is, after $D_1$ gives you red and $D_2$ gives you green, an alternate strategy is to draw from $D_1$ again (instead of $D_3$).  If my calculations are correct this also results in $5$ draws on average so is suboptimal...  Or perhaps you meant to rule these out by your comment that "we should try to avoid this procedure"?

Comment: @antkam: You are right; I did not give a proof that this is optimal.